# Как задать цвет разметке Grid в Wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

Делаю  верстку, интерфейс на WPF.Хочу сделать разметку рыжим цветом ,знаю что в Winforms есть Splitter.Помогите кто знает ,как сверстать разметку или изменить цвет ,такую как на фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="LightGreen">
        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="hello1"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="LightBlue">
        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="hello2"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightPink">
        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="hello3"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="LightSalmon">
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="hello4"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="LightYellow">
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="hello5"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="LightCyan">
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="hello6"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не используйте пиксельные размеры, тогда интерфейс будет выглядеть красиво на любом размере окна. Размеры колонок так же можно регулировать в относительных величинах. Например, если самому первому гриду задать колонки так

```xml
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

То получится вот такой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ!

Comment: Только вот хотел я использовать splitter для разметки границ ,но в wpf есть толькo gridsplitter

Comment: @ilya сплиттеры нужны чтобы юзер руками мог границы перетаскивать